# No exception on copying files in Linux with C++ streambuffer when disk almost full?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, fstream, ofstream

I'm trying to treat the case when the free disk space is less than the file I want to copy on it but from what I've tested it seems that I get no exception and the file is written truncated to the free space left on that disk.

For example, my source kept on another disk has 3MB, the destination disk has only 2MB free, then the file write will be truncated to the 2MB and no exception is thrown.

My sample code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


ifstream source("/some/other/disk/source.file", ios::binary);
ofstream dest("/my/almost/full/disk/dest.file", ios::binary);
dest.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );

try {

dest << source.rdbuf();

} catch (std::exception &ex) { /* not reached */

cout << "It's dead, Jim: " << ex.what() << endl;

}


source.close();
dest.close();

return 0;
}
```

The code behaves as expected (exception is thrown) only when the disk is full, filled-up beforehand.

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question. What OS? I'm a bit confused by the last part of the question: *The code behaves as expected (exception is thrown) only when the disk is full.* So does it work in the end and you get an exception?

Comment: "_no error will show up_", "_exception is thrown_", please, choose one.

Comment: isnt it better do validation first instead of forcing resources to write, for linux df -h or df -h . simply returns size of disk

Comment: @flatmouse: Linux 2.6.32 ;  the disk is filled-up before the write is attempted, this is what I mean by "the disk is full".

- YSC: ok, I'll go with exception

- HRgiger not doing it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Check `eof` once copying is done on your output stream. It should not be at `eof`. If file is copied this would be set.

The member function `eof` of ofstream should help.
Please refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/)

Edit 1: One other way I can think of performing `stat` on `dest` file and source as well and if that does not match then it is not copied fully. The other way will be to perform seek on `dest` and figure filesize without calling `stat` and then compare sizes. The problem is `stat` does not work on all OS so seek should do.

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream::pos_type filesize(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    return in.tellg(); 
}
```

This code can find filesize.

Comment: A print of:
    dest.eof();
after:dest << source.rdbuf() returns 0.

Comment: That means bit is not set i.e. eof on output stream has not been reached and file has not been copied fully. But then I am not very sure. Check this again when copy is completed fully.

Comment: The reason I am not sure is because that link says that input operations do this. But we are doing an output operation.

Comment: as you might observed, there's no loop to check this again "when copy is completed fully", I'm calling .eof() right after the dest << source.rdbuf(). And yes, eof would make sense to be related only to the source file, not the one to which I write.

Comment: You can check `dest.eof` before you close `dest`. Since there is nothing esle a 1 will prove what we are trying to achieve.